# How to complete column values

Tags: sql, postgresql

SQL script to complete a table

Hello,
I have the following challenge:

- two tables: table1 and table2
- table1 has a lookup-column(e.g. 'referencecolumn') to table2. Each record in table1 must point to one record in table2. Many records in table1 could point to the same record in table2

Unfortunately there are many datarecods in table1, which have 'wrong' values for table1.referencecolumn. The values are NULL or 0 and I need to fill them with the correct values.
Fortunately they are many other 'redundand' pointer columns in table1 to table2. But they yield **only together** a acceptable reference to a table2 record.

For example student exam records(table1) could point to only one examination regulation(table2) via column table1.examregulation

So I think I must do the following(SQL or python), but I'm very new to SQL and python :

```
FOREACH table1record where table1.referencecolumn is NULL or 0

IF 
((table1.column1 == table2.column1) AND (table1.column2 == table2.column2) AND
AND (table1.column3 == table2.column3) )
THEN SET table1.referencecolumn = table2.referencedcolumn
ENDIF

END FOREACH
```

---

@a_horse_with_no_name: thanks!
*'It's unclear to me if you want to permanently update the data or just change the result'* - I want to update/fillfill the data in table1 once.

table1

```
+------+------+------+-----------------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | referencecolumn |
+------+------+------+-----------------+
| ABB  | 2000 | 52   | NULL            |
| AKB  | 2001 | 61   | 0               |
| INB  | 1998 | 77   | 0               |
| ENM  | 2010 | 56   | NULL            |
+------+------+------+-----------------+
table2
+------+------+------+------------------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | referencedcolumn |
+------+------+------+------------------+
| ABB  | 2000 | 52   | 254              |
| AKB  | 2001 | 61   | 587              |
| INB  | 1998 | 77   | 665              |
| ENM  | 2010 | 56   | 322              |
+------+------+------+------------------+

RESULT after SQL UPDATE or run script: table1 looks like this:


+------+------+------+-----------------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | referencecolumn |
+------+------+------+-----------------+
| ABB  | 2000 | 52   | 254            |
| AKB  | 2001 | 61   | 587            |
| INB  | 1998 | 77   | 665            |
| ENM  | 2010 | 56   | 322            |
+------+------+------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: It's unclear to me if you want to permanently [`update`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html) the data in table or just change the result of a query

Answer (score 1):

Your update statement should be.

```
UPDATE Table1 t
  SET referencecolumn = s.referencedcolumn
FROM Table2 s
WHERE t.col1 = s.col1
    AND t.col2 = s.col2
    AND t.col3 = s.col3;
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me.